# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function cal_info()

Tags: php

for some reason my php application(PHP 7.2.34 (cli)) is crashing in this error.
I use cal_info function right here:

```
private function month($month, $abbrev = true)
    {
        $infos = cal_info( CAL_GREGORIAN );

        if($abbrev)
            return $infos['abbrevmonths'][intval($month)];
        else
            return $infos['months'][intval($month)];
    }
```

and return this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function cal_info()
can you guys help me?

Comment: Just to try, can you add a slash before the function? `\cal_info...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile your php-installation with `--enable-calendar`

You can read more about it and how to install it in the [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/calendar.installation.php).

Check your php-installation with by running `php -i` and search for `Configure Command`. It should contain `--enable-calendar` if you want to use the `cal_info()` function.
Instead of running `php -i` you can also write a short php-script and call `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, i am using docker, do you know what command i need to use?

Comment: You have to re-compile your php-installation on your own or your docker image need to support this. You should google about it: https://www.google.com/search?q=docker+php+enable+calendar

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you use a Dockerfile based on php:7.1, you can install the calendar extension by this way:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install calendar && docker-php-ext-configure calendar
```